# Docker x509 certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, docker-compose, certificate, ssl-certificate, docker-registry

To clear some space, I ran `docker system prune -a -f` and after that I can't build any image. Now when I run `sudo docker build -t test_image .` the output is

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.825GB
Step 1/9 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I am new to docker and don't know much. Please suggest me what to do ? Thanks.

Comment: Do any of these help? Please show how this is not a duplicate of an existing Q&A on the site. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker%5D+x509%3A+certificate+signed+by+unknown+authority&searchOn=3

Comment: This is different as in any of the previous post's answers, there isn't a way described to download/install the certificate and I don't know how to. If you know then please help.